# Flutter como obtener los datos de un json

Tags: json, lista, flutter, dart

Buenas tengo el siguiente inconveniente tengo un json el siguiente http://emovies.evolucionone.com/  y tengo la clase para obtener los datos para la cual use https://app.quicktype.io/ y el código es el siguiente

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final moviesFirstLoad = moviesFirstLoadFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

MoviesFirstLoad moviesFirstLoadFromJson(String str) {
  final jsonData = json.decode(str);
  return MoviesFirstLoad.fromJson(jsonData);
}

String moviesFirstLoadToJson(MoviesFirstLoad data) {
  final dyn = data.toJson();
  return json.encode(dyn);
}

class MoviesFirstLoad {
  List<Movierecent> movierecent;

  MoviesFirstLoad({
    this.movierecent,
  });

  factory MoviesFirstLoad.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => new MoviesFirstLoad(
    movierecent: new List<Movierecent>.from(json["movierecent"].map((x) => Movierecent.fromJson(x))),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "movierecent": new List<dynamic>.from(movierecent.map((x) => x.toJson())),
  };
}

class Movierecent {
  int id;
  String movieId;
  String title;
  String genre;
  String myear;
  String released;
  String runtime;
  String rated;
  String director;
  String actors;
  String plot;
  String imdbrating;
  String type;
  String production;
  int internalid;
  String poster;

  Movierecent({
    this.id,
    this.movieId,
    this.title,
    this.genre,
    this.myear,
    this.released,
    this.runtime,
    this.rated,
    this.director,
    this.actors,
    this.plot,
    this.imdbrating,
    this.type,
    this.production,
    this.internalid,
    this.poster,
  });

  factory Movierecent.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => new Movierecent(
    id: json["id"],
    movieId: json["movieID"],
    title: json["title"],
    genre: json["genre"],
    myear: json["myear"],
    released: json["released"],
    runtime: json["runtime"],
    rated: json["rated"],
    director: json["director"],
    actors: json["actors"],
    plot: json["plot"],
    imdbrating: json["imdbrating"],
    type: json["type"],
    production: json["production"],
    internalid: json["internalid"],
    poster: json["poster"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "movieID": movieId,
    "title": title,
    "genre": genre,
    "myear": myear,
    "released": released,
    "runtime": runtime,
    "rated": rated,
    "director": director,
    "actors": actors,
    "plot": plot,
    "imdbrating": imdbrating,
    "type": type,
    "production": production,
    "internalid": internalid,
    "poster": poster,
  };
}
```

ahora bien en la primera etiquetame muestra que debo utilizar

> final moviesFirstLoad = moviesFirstLoadFromJson(jsonString);

por lo tanto tengo lo siguiente y aqui no se que hacer como acceder los datos para colocarlos en una lista seria algo asi

> Future> loadMovies() async {
>
> ```
> final response = await http.get("http://emovies.evolucionone.com/");
> if (response.statusCode == 200){
>   final moviesFirstLoad = moviesFirstLoadFromJson(response.body);
>
> }else{
>   throw Exception ('Failed to load Data');
> }
> ```
>
> }

Necesito ayuda para obtener los datos del json si alguien me ayuda ya he leido varios temas pero ninguno me funciona...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar un `FutureBuilder` o `StatefulWidget`.

Te dejo un ejemplo con `FutureBuilder` este widget recibe un `future` al que le pasaré tu método asíncrono que obtiene datos de la web. El cual pasa a un `builder` con los datos obtenidos de la llamada asíncrona.

> He generado un modelo con el json de tu página, pero me generó un poco diferente al tuyo, te dejo el código completo.

**movie.dart (modelo)**

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final welcome = welcomeFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

AppData moviesFirstLoadFromJson(String str) {
  final jsonData = json.decode(str);
  return AppData.fromJson(jsonData);
}

String moviesFirstToJson(AppData data) {
  final dyn = data.toJson();
  return json.encode(dyn);
}

class AppData {
  List<Movierecent> movierecent;

  AppData({
    this.movierecent,
  });

  factory AppData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => new AppData(
        movierecent: new List<Movierecent>.from(
            json["movierecent"].map((x) => Movierecent.fromJson(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "movierecent":
            new List<dynamic>.from(movierecent.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      };
}

class Movierecent {
  int id;
  String movieId;
  String title;
  String genre;
  String myear;
  String released;
  String runtime;
  String rated;
  String director;
  String actors;
  String plot;
  String imdbrating;
  String type;
  String production;
  int internalid;
  String poster;

  Movierecent({
    this.id,
    this.movieId,
    this.title,
    this.genre,
    this.myear,
    this.released,
    this.runtime,
    this.rated,
    this.director,
    this.actors,
    this.plot,
    this.imdbrating,
    this.type,
    this.production,
    this.internalid,
    this.poster,
  });

  factory Movierecent.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => new Movierecent(
        id: json["id"],
        movieId: json["movieID"],
        title: json["title"],
        genre: json["genre"],
        myear: json["myear"],
        released: json["released"],
        runtime: json["runtime"],
        rated: json["rated"],
        director: json["director"],
        actors: json["actors"],
        plot: json["plot"],
        imdbrating: json["imdbrating"],
        type: json["type"],
        production: json["production"],
        internalid: json["internalid"],
        poster: json["poster"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "movieID": movieId,
        "title": title,
        "genre": genre,
        "myear": myear,
        "released": released,
        "runtime": runtime,
        "rated": rated,
        "director": director,
        "actors": actors,
        "plot": plot,
        "imdbrating": imdbrating,
        "type": type,
        "production": production,
        "internalid": internalid,
        "poster": poster,
      };
}
```

**home_screen.dart**

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

import 'movie.dart';


class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  Future<AppData> loadMovies() async {
    final response = await http.get("http://emovies.evolucionone.com/");
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final AppData moviesFirstLoad = moviesFirstLoadFromJson(response.body);
      return moviesFirstLoad;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load Data');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Películas')),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: loadMovies(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<AppData> snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data.movierecent.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              final Movierecent movie = snapshot.data.movierecent[index];
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(movie.title),
                subtitle: Text(movie.genre),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvió perfecto tu respuesta. Se agradece la ayuda. espero sirva para otras personas que tengan el mismo problema